# How to add runtime annotations on scala synthetic methods?

Tags: scala, annotations, jvm

For example, with the following definitions

```
class A
class B extends A

trait MyTrait {
  @MyAnnotation
  def foo(): A
}

class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  @MyAnnotation
  def foo() = new B
}
```

Scala generates a synthetic method foo() that returns A in MyClass. Looking at the produced bytecode (with javap) i can see:

```
  public net.bdew.mytest.test.B foo();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: new           #15                 // class net/bdew/mytest/test/B
     3: dup           
     4: invokespecial #19                 // Method net/bdew/mytest/test/B."<init>":()V
     7: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       8     0  this   Lnet/bdew/mytest/test/MyClass;
      LineNumberTable:
    line 22: 0
    RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
      0: #13()
```

That's the real method and the annotation is present on it.

```
  public net.bdew.mytest.test.A foo();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0       
     1: invokevirtual #24                 // Method foo:()Lnet/bdew/mytest/test/B;
     4: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       5     0  this   Lnet/bdew/mytest/test/MyClass;
      LineNumberTable:
    line 20: 0
```

That's the synthetic, without an annotation. Is there any way to have it appear on it as well?

Edit: to clarify MyAnnotation is defined in java with runtime retention.